# Is the use of the word "better" correct in this text?

Tags: word-in-context

Is the use of the word "better" correct in this text? Or rather, does the text, as a whole, make any sense?

I'm completely exhausted. Sometimes I really feel that I better get myself out of this relationship and start a new life in another place.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is a correct use of `better`.

Merriam-Webster calls that sense of "better" an auxiliary verb, with the same meaning as "had better":
[Merriam-Webster "better" (5)](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/better#h3)
better *auxiliary verb*
**had better**
example: *you `better` hurry*

Cambridge provides an explanation of "had better":
[Cambridge Dictionary "had better"](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/had-better)
"We use 'had better' ... to talk about actions we think people should do or which are desirable in a specific situation."

So, the meaning of "had better" (an auxiliary verb followed by the adverb "better", meaning "preferably") is similar to the meaning of the auxiliary verb "should".

Then, speaking less formally, the "had" can be dropped, and "better" becomes an auxiliary verb itself, with the same meaning.